# Not selecting userId if not in role (admin), multiple roles in one user

Tags: sql, sql-server

Is it possible to select only the id's of the users that have admin role(role id = 3) without using NOT IN(same query with roleid)? 
Each user has different roles(user, manager, admin, etc).

```
SELECT appUserInGroups.UserId, appRoles.RoleName, appRoles.RoleId
FROM appGroupInRoles 
        INNER JOIN appRoles ON appGroupInRoles.RoleId = appRoles.RoleId 
        INNER JOIN appUserInGroups ON appGroupInRoles.GroupId = appUserInGroups.GroupId 
        INNER JOIN appApplications ON appRoles.ApplicationId = appApplications.ApplicationId
WHERE appGroupInRoles.UserId not in ( SELECT appUserInGroups.UserId
                                        FROM appGroupInRoles 
                                          INNER JOIN appRoles ON appGroupInRoles.RoleId = appRoles.RoleId 
                                          INNER JOIN appUserInGroups ON appGroupInRoles.GroupId = appUserInGroups.GroupId 
                                         INNER JOIN appApplications ON appRoles.ApplicationId = appApplications.ApplicationId
                                          WHERE appGroupInRoles.RoleId = 3)
```

The NOT IN kills performance completely. 
User Roles preview: 
[image: User Roles preview]

Comment: `Each user has different roles` ... Are you saying a user can have more than one role?

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn yes, its written in the header.

Comment: Why are you using NOT IN? If I'm understanding you correctly, you're looking for the users with the admin role, right? So you'd use IN

Comment: Is `appUserInGroups.UserId` nullable? Please can you post the execution plan? You may wish to try with `NOT EXISTS` instead of `NOT IN`, these can yield the same plan, or `NOT EXISTS` can yield a superior plan, I have never seen it yield a worse plan though, so with no execution plan, table or index definitions this would be my best guess so far.

Comment: @ChrisForrence because i dont want the userId that has a admin role. userId 1, this user has admin, manager, etc. so i dont want the user id.

Comment: @BrunoMartins - Alright, so to be clear, you're looking for users that do not have the admin role as one of their assigned roles, correct? (I ask because the question seems a little ambiguous)

Comment: @GarethD The userId is not nullable. i Edited the post to add a picture.

Comment: @ChrisForrence yes. without using NOT IN because it kills performance.

Comment: That is the results, not the execution plan. Can you post that (there is a button on the tool bar, or select "Include actual execution plan" from the query menu).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
WITH Admins AS
(
   SELECT appUserInGroups.UserId AS uID
   FROM appGroupInRoles 
   INNER JOIN appUserInGroups ON appGroupInRoles.GroupId = appUserInGroups.GroupId 
   WHERE appGroupInRoles.RoleId = 3
)
SELECT appUserInGroups.UserId, appRoles.RoleName, appRoles.RoleId
FROM appGroupInRoles 
INNER JOIN appRoles ON appGroupInRoles.RoleId = appRoles.RoleId 
INNER JOIN appUserInGroups ON appGroupInRoles.GroupId = appUserInGroups.GroupId 
INNER JOIN appApplications ON appRoles.ApplicationId = appApplications.ApplicationId
LEFT JOIN Admins on appGroupInRoles.UserId = Admins.uID
WHERE Admins.uID is null
```

I removed some extra joins from the sub-query and added it as a CTE.  I also used a left join instead of not in (which should actually compile in the execution plan the same) but added it to show you the "other way" to do it.

This should have the same exact execution plan as the following if the optimizer is working well.

```
SELECT appUserInGroups.UserId, appRoles.RoleName, appRoles.RoleId
FROM appGroupInRoles 
INNER JOIN appRoles ON appGroupInRoles.RoleId = appRoles.RoleId 
INNER JOIN appUserInGroups ON appGroupInRoles.GroupId = appUserInGroups.GroupId 
INNER JOIN appApplications ON appRoles.ApplicationId = appApplications.ApplicationId
WHERE appGroupInRoles.UserId NOT IN (
   SELECT appUserInGroups.UserId AS uID
   FROM appGroupInRoles 
   INNER JOIN appUserInGroups ON appGroupInRoles.GroupId = appUserInGroups.GroupId 
   WHERE appGroupInRoles.RoleId = 3
)
```

*EDIT:  See link in comments for a nice post explaining why you should always use NOT EXISTS on SQL Server.  Random side note; from my experience you should use NOT IN on DB2*

Comment: I am not disputing it, but I am genuinely surprised if using `LEFT JOIN` offers a performance gain, I think the real gain is removing unnecessary joins. `LEFT JOIN/IS NULL` can yield the same plan as `NOT IN/NOT EXISTS`, but it is often worse as it cannot utilize an anti semi join - [NOT IN vs. NOT EXISTS vs. LEFT JOIN / IS NULL: SQL Server](http://explainextended.com/2009/09/15/not-in-vs-not-exists-vs-left-join-is-null-sql-server/)

Comment: @GarethD - as that link explains, "SQL Server's optimizer cannot discern an ANTI JOIN in a LEFT JOIN / IS NULL construct."  As I said in my answer "if the optimizer is working well."  Clearly the optimizer isn't in SQL Server's case.  So the best choice is to use `NOT EXISTS`.  Thanks for the link.

Answer (score 1):

Try an exclusion join:

```
SELECT u.UserId, r.RoleName, r.RoleId
FROM appUserInGroups u
INNER JOIN appGroupInRoles g on g.GroupId = u.GroupId
INNER JOIN appRoles r ON r.RoleId = g.RoleId
LEFT JOIN (
    --Admin Users
    SELECT u.UserId
    FROM appUserInGroups u
    INNER JOIN appGroupInRoles g on g.GroupId = u.GroupId and g.RoleID=3
) a on a.UserId = u.UserId
WHERE a.UserId IS NULL
```

Not sure what you were doing with the `appApplications` table, and it seemed like the order you were looking at a the tables was a little strange... like you were starting in the middle.

You might be able to do even a little better still with a `NOT EXISTS` query.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an analytic function to tell you if a user has roleid 3. I don't know if this is faster, though.

```
select distinct userid, rolename, roleid
from
(
  SELECT 
    appUserInGroups.UserId, 
    appRoles.RoleName, 
    appRoles.RoleId,
    max(case when appRoles.RoleId = 3 then 1 else 0 end) over (partition by appUserInGroups.UserId) as has3
  FROM appGroupInRoles 
  INNER JOIN appRoles ON appGroupInRoles.RoleId = appRoles.RoleId 
  INNER JOIN appUserInGroups ON appGroupInRoles.GroupId = appUserInGroups.GroupId 
  INNER JOIN appApplications ON appRoles.ApplicationId = appApplications.ApplicationId
)
where has3 = 0;
```

I also added DISTINCT, because a user my be granted a roleid by memebership of different groups, so you would get duplicates without DISTINCT.